# Firebase functions setInterval and clearInterval on separate calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, setinterval

I have two APIs, the first is start setInterval and second is clearInterval. Of course the second API doesn't work, but how to make it work? As I understand there is no global variable where I can assign setInterval. Any ideas?

```
let glob = 0;
let timer = null;

exports.start = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if(timer){
    }else {
      queueFunction();
    }
    res.status(status).send(mes);
  });
});

exports.stop= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if(timer){
      clearInterval(timer);
    }else {
    }
    res.status(status).send(mes);
  });
});

function queueFunction() {
 timer = setInterval(timerFunc, 3000);
}

function timerFunc(){
  glob++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible.  Each function runs in a completely isolated server instance.  They know nothing about each other, and have no shared state.

Furthermore, after an HTTP function sends a response, it is effectively terminated and cleaned up.   You cannot have ongoing work continue in that server instance after a function is terminated.

If you need to persist some state in your function, you should use a storage mechanism such as Realtime Database or Firestore.  If you need work to appear to continue after a function terminates, you will have to spin up another function, typically via pub/sub.  Or you can delegate to another server instance such as App Engine.

Comment: The setInterval keeps working, strange but yes. I set interval for every hour to write to a firestore and I had a collection with data. But you are right that the way I started to implement it is completely wrong. Thx